# Python3 insert into MariaDB fails

Tags: python-3.x, mariadb

i want to insert data from the Alecto WS-1200 weather station which I read on my raspberry pi 3 with the RF Link software running on a arduino mega connected to the RPI via USB.

I see in phpmyadmin that no row is inserted and the DB is empty.

Here's my code:

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb
import serial

#Initialization
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=57600)

#Read sensor
while True:
   readBytes = ser.readline()
   line = readBytes.decode("utf-8")
   print(line)
   list = line.split(";")
   if list[2] == "Alecto V5":
      rain = list[5].split("RAIN=", 1)[1]
      rainFloat = float.fromhex(rain)
      rainFloat = rainFloat / 10
      mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(host='localhost', user='test', password='test', database='test')
      cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

      try:
         cursor.execute("SELECT interpolated FROM rain_data ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1")
         result = cursor.fetchone()
         if result is not None:
            previousVal = result[0]
            if rainFloat - previousVal >= 0:
               interpolated = rainFloat - previousVal
               cursor.execute("INSERT INTO rain_data (interpolated, raw_value) VALUES (%s, %s)", interpolated, rainFloat)
            else:
               cursor.execute("INSERT INTO rain_data (interpolated, raw_value) VALUES (%s, %s)", rainFloat, rainFloat)
         else:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO rain_data (interpolated, raw_value) VALUES (%s, %s)", rainFloat, rainFloat)
            print(cursor.rowcount)
      except mariadb.Error as error:
         print("Error: {}".format(error))
      finally:
         mariadb_connection.commit()
         mariadb_connection.close()
```

Unfortunalety this code doesn't work though the insert statement is executed. The rowcount returns -1. No error code is thrown. A similar insert statement however is working in another script.
Since I see the row code I assume that the insert statement is exevuted.

The serial connection just returns a string like 20;00Alecto V5;Temp=07d;BAT=OK;RAIN=03f
As you see i format it just to extract the hex value of the rain to insert it in the DB.

What am I missing?

Comment: If the insert succeeds (as in: your data is properly inserted in the db) then the issue is possibly with your [transaction isolation level](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/set-transaction/), or with [using non-buffered cursors] (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-rowcount.html).

Comment: The problem is that the data isn't inserted in the DB. No error is thrown but now data is inserted. The table stays empty. SO do you still think this is an isolation level issue?

Comment: "the data isn't inserted in the DB" => so you should _really_ edit your post to make the point clearer - I understood the " this code doesn't work though the insert statement is executed" as meaning your data was inserted but `rowcount` still yielded `-1`.  But how do you know that "the insert statement is executed" then ?  Please edit your post to include a proper [mcve].

Comment: Okay, sorry for the misunderstanding, I updated the question. Also I will try to generate a code tomorrow that can be run anywhere that produces the same behaviour.

Comment: What do you mean by "Since I see the row code" ??? Hint: python has [a step debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), it can really helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it's really simple: I just forgot the parentheses around the values of the insert statement.

Changing this line:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO rain_data (interpolated, raw_value) VALUES (%s, %s)", rainFloat, rainFloat)
```

To this did the trick:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO rain_data (interpolated, raw_value) VALUES (%s, %s)", (rainFloat, rainFloat))
```